# Openpyxl - Transfer range of rows from a worksheet to another

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I want to take a certain part of data from a sheet and copy it to another sheet.

So far, I have a dictionary with key as start row and value as end row.

Using this, I would like to do the following:

-Get the first range from sheet0 and append it to sheet1

-Get the second range from sheet0 and append it to sheet2

-Get the third range from sheet0 and append it to sheet3

I tried the following:

```
#First range starts at 1 and ends at 34, second range from 34-52 and third from 52-75
myDict = {1: 34, 34: 52, 52: 75}

#store all the sheets, ignoring main sheet
sheet = wb.worksheets[1:] 


for item in myDict:
    for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=item, max_row=myDict[item], min_col=1 , max_col=ws.max_column):
        for cell in col:
            for z in sheet:
                z.append(col)
```

Another approach was to use a function and lists:

```
startRow=[1,34,52]
endRow=[34,52,75]

def addRange(first, second):
    for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=first, max_row=second, min_col=1 , max_col=ws.max_column):
        for cell in col:
            for z in sheet:
                z.append(col)    

#Call function    
for start, end in zip(startRow, endRow):
    addRange(start, end)
```

But on both occasions, I get the following error "ValueError: Cells cannot be copied from other worksheets"

Does anyone have a clue on what am I missing in here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a couple of things i noticed : there is no declaration for ws in ur code. u cant append col to sheet. u r to append values. as such u have to iterate to the cell level then add the cell value to ur sheet. find a way to zip the sheet names with the ranges, that should make ur iteration easier

Comment: Thanks for the questions Sammy. I didn't add the unnecessary intro code. ws was made like this: #wb = xl.Workbook()
#ws = wb.active

Comment: @sammywemmy I added 'for cell in col' to iterate through the cells.

Comment: share a sample file, and I'll play with it to see where the issue might be, or suggest other methods

Comment: @sammywemmy I added the Excel file and an Info notepad file in here using WeTransfer: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a483c979012d99eda9634168e1d0342920200520085221/1a3a15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from itertools import product

filename = 'wetransfer-a483c9/testFile.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename)

sheets = wb.sheetnames[1:]
```

Where `sheets` would be `['Table 1', 'Table 2', 'Table 3']`

```
# access the main worksheet
ws = wb['Main']
```

First, get the boundaries (start-/endpoint) for each Table

```
span = []
for row in ws:
    for cell in row:
        if (cell.value
                and (cell.column == 2)  # restrict search to column2, which is where the Table entries are
                # this also avoids the int error, since integers are not iterable
                and ("Table" in cell.value)):
            span.append(cell.row)

# add sheet's length -> allows us to effectively capture the data boundaries
span.append(ws.max_row + 1)
```

Result `span` : `[1, 29, 42, 58]`

Second, get the pairing of boundaries. `+1` ensures the end is included when capturing the tables and convert them to *string* format
Since openpyxl refers to the boundaries in string form and has a 1 index notation, instead of adding 1, you have to take one off.

```
boundaries = [":".join(map(str,(start, end-1)))  for start, end in zip(span,span[1:])]
```

Result `boundaries` : `['1:28', '29:41', '42:57']`

Third, create a cartesian of the main sheet, the boundaries and the other sheets. Note that boundaries and sheets are zipped - essentially they are a pair. As such, we paired each table with a boundary:

```
#table 1 is bound to 1:28,
#table 2 is bound to 29:41, ...
```

Next, we combine the main sheet with the pair, so main sheet is paired with `(table 1, 1:28)`. The same main sheet is paired with `(table 2, 29:41) ...`

Fourth, get the data within the ranges. Since we have successfully paired the main sheet with every pair of table and boundary, we can safely get the data for that particular region and shift it to the particular table.

So  `table 1` in the main sheet refers to `1:28`, since it is bound to this particular table. When it's done with `table 1`, it returns to the loop and starts at "Table 2", selecting only "29:41" since this is the limit in this section, and so on.

```
for main,(ref, table) in product([ws],zip(boundaries, sheets)):

    sheet_content = main[ref]
    # append row to the specified table

    for row in sheet_content:
        #here we iterate through the main sheet
        #get one row of data
        #append it to the table
        #move to the next row, append to the table beneath the previous one
        #and repeat the process till the boundary has been exhausted
        wb[table].append([cell.value for cell in row])
```

Finally, save your file.

```
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: is it's not too much, could you please clarify the code starting from "#create a cartesian of the main sheet, the boundaries and the other sheets". I don't quite get how this works.

Comment: made some comments in the code. lemme know if u need more details

Comment: hello @sammywemmy, I know this topic was closed but I tried the same code on a similar file and got the following error: "TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable" on this code "wb[table].append([cell.value for cell in row])"

Comment: hi. is there any specific difference between the files. its been a while, so i definitely have forgotten details about it. you could shoot me a copy of the file and i'll have a look at it

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, I added the random DB I found on the internet in here "https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5528acd9dc22b9ceb89d2d4306c4e3af20200724080230/36f50c". 
There are 7 Tables which I want to take from main sheet and copy/paste each table in their own new sheet. Table 1 sheet should contain table 1 contents, Table 2 sheet should contain table 2 contents, and so on..

Comment: As I mentioned, the interesting part is that the code worked on a similar file but not for this one as I'm getting " TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable" on following code "wb[table].append([cell.value for cell in row])"

Comment: sammywemmy, got any clue on what's wrong with this file as it makes the code to break at the last append?

Comment: made changes to the code. removed unnecessary bloat. it should be much better now. I also made comments at relevant points within the code. Let me know how it goes

Comment: you sir, are a genius! It worked now. My only concern is the time efficiency. It took 3 minutes to finish 6 tables. Will look further on how can I make it more efficient. 
Thank you so much @sammywemmy!

Comment: glad it worked for you. let me know about the efficiency improvements. it would be useful learning for me as well. cheers