# Splitting Large CSV file into multiple sheets in a single Excel using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am using this piece of code for reading a csv(around 1 GB) using pandas and then writing into multiple excel sheets using chunksize.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('/tmp/output.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        reader = pd.read_csv(f'/tmp/{file_name}', sep=',', chunksize=1000000)
        for idx, chunk in enumerate(reader):
            chunk.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"Report (P_{idx + 1})", index=False)
        writer.save()
```

This approach is taking a lot of time .Can anyone please suggest any approaches to reduce this time?

Comment: Do you want to use Pandas library only? There are other libraries which will work better for this purpose.

Comment: I can use other Python packages as long they are open source and don't have any licensing issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - split large excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321082/pandas-split-large-excel-file)

Comment: you can do this with python's csv module and openpyxl. no need for Pandas here, since there is no data manipulation involved. Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61927477/7175713) and see if it is relevant. Also, how long does your current process take?

Comment: I finally used [PyExcelerate](https://pypi.org/project/PyExcelerate/)  for my use case

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago i have faced same problem so i tried with

you can use library called as vaex
[1]: https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Or if you to to do itself with pandas try to use apache pyspark

Or use can use Google colud with 1200 credit

Comment: I want to write the large csv to an excel wtith multiple sheets.I was not able to find any excel related utility in this package.Visualization is not my requirement.

Comment: Then use google colab or google clod  for free esle there in no option